# How do you maximize distance between closest points in set?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I have a set of 2D points: (x1,y1) … (xn,yn). I like to divide the points into two sets such that the closest pair of points in each set is maximized. Is there an algorithm for that?

Clarification: The closest pair of points (both in the same set) in each set is maximized. So it's not k-means (which minimizes the furthest point from the center of the cluster).

Comment: Find the closest pair globally and put the two points in separate sets?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError And what do you do with all the other points?

Comment: https://stackabuse.com/k-means-clustering-with-scikit-learn/

Comment: as a code: https://miguelmota.com/blog/k-means-clustering-in-javascript/

Comment: See my clarification. The closest pair of points (both in the same set) in each set is maximized. So it's not k-means (which minimizes the furthest point from the center of the cluster).

Comment: You cannot maximize two things at a time. Please restate the objective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To rephrase: nearby pairs of points should go in opposite sets if possible.

My suggestion would be to compute a minimum spanning tree (O(n log n) via your favorite Delaunay triangulation algorithm) and then two-color it with a depth-first search (O(n)).

This maximizes the distance between the two closest points in a single set. We know that this distance is at least d if, when we extract all pairs closer than d, the resulting graph is bipartite. If you imagine that we compute the MST using the inefficient Kruskal's algorithm, which sorts the edges by distance and considers them in order, then it's hopefully clear that this algorithm in essence tries greedily to accommodate the requirements of each edge in order, giving up only when an odd cycle is about to form.

In particular, the nearest neighbor of each node is in the opposite set.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense to me. Will depends on the degree of the vertices in the tree, but I think this will be great for this application.

Comment: @nickponline please ping me if a balance requirement turns out to be necessary.

Comment: Ideally the split sets will have the same size.

Comment: @nickponline exactly, or approximately?

Comment: Only approximately.

Comment: @nickponline if the point set isn't too large, I'd try Kruskal + online bipartite coloring, but refuse to add an edge if it forces the balance too far out of alignment (use the subset sum DP to check).